# работа с базой данных в localstorageDB

Tags: javascript, localstorage

скачал библиотеку localstorageDB но к сожалению у ней нет русской документации, а та что на агнлийском для меня скудновата не могу понять
[вот тут она находится](https://devhub.io/repos/whazap-Indexed-localStorageDB)

собственно моя проблема вот в чем такой код:

```
  var nur_z = false; //переменная что бы чекнуть наличие строк в БД
  var squ_z = res.oid; //тут у меня лежи ключь по которому ищу
  var res_z; //зарание определил переменную для записи результата
        lib.queryAll("omi_zmet", {
            query: function(row) {
                if(row.oid == squ_z) { //если есть совпадение проверяем
                    nur_z = true; //ставим отметку что результат есть
                    res_z = row; //по идее записываем нашу выборку в переменную
                }
            }
        });
```

и вот дальше нам надо как то выборку нашу разобрать например через какой нибудь foreach

```
if (nur_z) {//проверяем опять же была ли выборка
    res_z.forEach(function(item, i, arr) { //собственно разбираем выборку
     alert( 'покажите мне хоть что то!' );
    });

 }
```

но проблема в том что цикл выдает мне

```
 TypeError: res_z.forEach is not a function
```

подскажите пожалуйста что не так? может я не правильно что то разбираю? в БД 100% есть нужные значения я проверяю через консоль в хранилище
данные по идее должы быть судя по документации в таком формате:

```
/* results
[
{
  ID: 1,
  code: "B001",
  title: "Phantoms in the brain",
  author: "Ramachandran",
   year: 1999,
   copies: 10
 },
 {
   ID: 2,
   code: "B002",
  title: "The tell-tale brain",
   author: "Ramachandran",
   year: 2011,
   copies: 10
 }
]
*/
```

как такое правильно разбирать???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**row** объект и не имеет метода *forEach* вы присваиваете результат, а надо добавлять. И бегло глянул доку колбек query должен возвращать результат bool

```
var res_z = []; // для записи результата
var rslt = lib.queryAll("omi_zmet", { //подозреваю rslt будет не пустой(если в бд что-то есть
    query: function(row) {
       if(row.oid == squ_z) { //если есть совпадение проверяем
           nur_z = true; //ставим отметку что результат есть
           res_z.push(row); //по идее записываем нашу выборку в переменную
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
});
```